# Erro "Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver" no Wordpress em localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost

Estou tentando colocar um site em Wordpress no Xampp (localhost) porém ao executa-lo aparece o seguinte erro:

Meu erro: https://prnt.sc/gjytdc

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\painel\include\PDO\pdopaginator.inc.php:16
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\painel\include\PDO\pdopaginator.inc.php(16):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '1234', NULL) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\painel\include\class.connection.inc.php(30):
>   PDOPaginator->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '1234') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\painel\global.php(35):
>   connection->connect() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\index.php(17):
>   require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phdvital\public_html\painel\include\PDO\pdopaginator.inc.php
>   on line 16

Já habilite a extension_pdo, extension_mysql do php.init, estou usando o **PHP 7.1.8** e tabém jé dei o phpinfo e funcionou normalmente.

Meu phpinfo: https://prnt.sc/gjysdn https://prnt.sc/gjyt77

Obs:O meu xampp não está instalado o Mysql pois ele está instalado a parte.

Comment: Qual versão do php vc usa? olhou no `phpinfo()` se consta o driver do mysql na parte do PDO (deveria estar habilitado)?

Comment: Estou usando a versao do PHP 5.6 e sim ja dei o phpinfo e funciona normalmente.

Comment: Poderia colocar o screenshot (na pergunta) da parte do PDO?

Comment: O módulo `pdo_mysql` está habilitado? Provavelmente no `php.ini` será necessário descomentar a linha `extension=php_pdo.dll` e `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Comment: sim o modulo esta habilitado.

Comment: Você não está usando o PHP 5.6 e sim o 7.18 conforme a imagem que você disponibilizou. Existe essa linha `<IfModule php5_module>` no ficheiro `httpd-xampp.conf`? Se sim, epxerimente trocar por `php7`.

Comment: É verdade, mais é estranho pois estava apontando para o 5.6, porém acredito que as instruções a seguir são as mesmas?

Comment: Provavelmente você está a editar o `php.ini`errado. Qual o resultado do `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);` ? Podes postar a imagem? Tente colocar a imagem no próprio Stackoverflow ( é recomendado ) pois servidores externos podem deixar de funcionar e a pergunta perde um pouco do contexto. Veja [esse link](http://tektriks.com/how-to-upgrade-php-5-6-to-php-7-in-xampp-on-windows/), você ajustou a migração do PHP 5 para o 7?

Comment: No meu `httpd-xampp.conf` nao tem o `<IfModule php5_module` ( meu arquivo: [https://prnt.sc/gjz0zz] | [https://prnt.sc/gjz169] | [https://prnt.sc/gjz1d1] e meu `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)` [https://prnt.sc/gjz1z3]

Comment: Você está alterando o `php.ini` que está na pasta `C:\xamp\php\php.ini` conforme está no `phpinfo`? Aparentemente pelas as imagens não há nada errado. Acredito que o problema está na configuração do MySql. Como é uma instalação a parte, o serviço do MySql está a funcionar?

Comment: Estou usando um mysql já instalado na maquina antes do Xampp.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65451/discussion-between-william-and-filipe-moraes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Abra o php.ini (**e não** o httpd-xampp.conf), o php.ini do Xampp deve estar em uma pasta semelhante a isto `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`, no notepad nativo do windows talvez não abra corretamente, pode abrir por programas como SublimeText ou Notepad++.

Após abrir, localize as linhas que contenham:

```
;extension=php_pdo.dll
```

e

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Tire o `;` e da frente, ficando:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

e

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Se for PHP7 (tanto Windows quanto Linux) deve estar assim:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

Remova o ; e ficando:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

E então **salve** o arquivo/ficheiro apertando Ctrl+S, em seguida **é necessário** reiniciar **o Apache** (no caso deve fazer isto no Painel do Xampp), aperte o botão Stop e depois que ele virar Start aperte novamente:

[image: imagem ilustrativa de uma versão antiga do Xampp]

Comment: já tirei os **;** do php.ini mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Ele já fez isso tudo. O problema é que o MySql é uma instalação a parte do Xampp, acredito que o problema está ai.

Comment: Não estou usando o mysql do xampp.

Comment: @William reiniciou o Apache? Se sim crie um arquivo php vazio chamado teste.php e então adicione dentro dele isto `<?php phpinfo();`, salve e execute no navegador isto `http://localhost/teste.php`, tire uma Screen do resultado e me mande (tem plugins para navegador que fazem isso).

Comment: @William esse erro não tem haver com o mysql. Continue conforme eu falei

Comment: @FilipeMoraes se o problema é no mysql então a mensagem de erro deveria ter mudado, se a mensagem continua é porque falta o `php_pdo_mysql`, se a mensagem for diferente do que esta na pergunta ele deve informar no corpo da pergunta para então eu ter um parâmetro do que pode ser o problema.

Comment: Meu phpinfo() https://prnt.sc/gjz90o

Comment: Sim, mas as informações que você está a solicitar estão todas nos comentários da pergunta, eu já pedi isso mas não consigo encontrar o problema. Veja os comentários da pergunta.

Comment: @William vc tirou foto da tela, eu quero a foto da página toda, o proprio plugin light faz isso, seleciona a opção "whole page" ou "entire page".

Comment: @FilipeMoraes não tem nada lá, só esta falando de httpd.conf, e isso é sobre o Apache, não vi nenhum comentário que falou que mudou a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @William a mensagem de erro ainda é `could not find driver`?

Comment: Sim essa é a mensagem.

Comment: @William então ou você não editou o arquivo corretamente ou não reiniciou o Apache devidamente. No `phpinfo`, tira o print da página inteira como te falei pra termos certeza.

Comment: @William se estiver usando o chrome instala esse add-on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screenshot/glgomjpomoahpeekneidkinhcfjnnhmb e tira um screen da página pra mim por favor.